# How to read a textfile, that is delimited by whitespaces, into a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file that is formatted this way:

```
A00     0010  00000
A001    0011  00000
A00911  0019  00000
A0100   0020  10000
```

I want to read this file into a DataFrame. So I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
path = *file path*
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep = '\t', header = None)
```

What I got was a DataFrame with 4 rows and one column.

```
                         0
0      A00     0010  00000
1      A001    0011  00000
2      A00911  0019  00000
3      A0100   0020  10000

[4 rows x 1 columns]
```

This is because the values are not seperated by "\t". The number of spaces between the columns vary in each row depending on the length of the string.

The desired DataFrame should have four rows and three columns.

```
          0       1      2  
0      A000    0010  00000
1      A001    0011  00000
2      A009    0019  00000
3      A0100   0020  10000

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Been a while since I touched pandas, but if you use `' '` instead of `'\t'`, does it not work?

Comment: No, I tried that.

Comment: Use `delim_whitespace`: `pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, dtype=str)`

Comment: @NickilMaveli, This is what I was looking for. Thanks! I will accept the answer if you post it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could supply `delim_whitespace=True` along with `dtype=str` to preserve the dtypes args in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), like:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, dtype=str)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try to use regex in the "sep" command

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep = ' +', header = None)
```

Comment: You might want to preserve numerical strings as they are and not cast them to ints, something like `pd.read_csv(path, sep = ' +', header = None, engine='python', converters={1: str, 2: str})`